# Custom theme not loading css Drupal 8

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I am creating a drupal theme but the css is not loading.

I already cleared the cache but it's still not loading.

My `info.yml`

```
name: Waluigi
description: Just a test
type: theme
core: 8.x

libraries:
  -waluigi/global-styling
```

My `libraries.yml`

```
global-styling:
  version: VERSION
  css:
    theme:
      css/style.css: {}
```

The stylesheet is placed at /themes/custom/waluigi/css

Can somebody tell me what I am missing?

Comment: Do you get an error message or is it just not loading?

Comment: No, it's just not loading.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a space after after the "-". So it should be like this:

```
- waluigi/global-styling
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh I had to put a space after the hyphen.

```
  - waluigi/global-styling
```